# What is the equivalent type annotation for leaving it empty

Tags: typescript

Which type annotation is leaving off the type annotation equivalent to?

If I do:

```
interface Foo {
 blah : string,
 bar
}
```

what is bar equivalent to? 
I thought it might be `any` or `bar ?: Bar` or `bar : Bar | undefined`
Is it one of these or something else?

Comment: `bar: any` or `bar?: any` I can see, but what is `Bar` and why would it enter into the picture here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bar` is `any` type, you can check it by declaring `Foo` interface as type:

```
type Foo = {
  blah: string,
  bar
}
```

`Foo` on hover will return `{ blah: string, bar: any }` type.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure what's the type of a variable, copy/paste that code to the Playground and hover the mouse pointer over this variable.

Try it here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkBGANnABbIBcyAzmFKAOYA0+BcUuAvkA

you can also hover the mouse pointer over the variable in question in your IDE.